# Spring security, JSESSIONID copy issue

Tags: spring, security, jsessionid

I am using spring security(Forms authentication) to authenticate incoming user. We logged-in with genuine userid and password. Now i just copied JSESSIONID from browser and created new Http request from android and passed same JSESSIONID to spring service. Request got authorized from android as well.

This means anyone can breach security once he got proper JSESSIONID.

How we can avoid this situation in spring security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a real threat.

Your threat model is: User can authenticate and copy their own session ID to another machine they control.

A hacker cannot steal someone else's session ID. That's the important part.

Comment: well, but if some one did manage to get one through some browser spyware, then how to go about it.